# Synology DS210j & online backup: what do people recommend?

Tags: network-attached-storage, synology, online-storage, backup

I've just purchased a Synology DS210j for my home network and would like to backup this NAS online. I noticed that DiskStation Manager v2.3 provides various options including Amazon S3 and rsync:

- Does anybody have some real usage
  against cost statistics for Amazon's
  S3 service?
- How is sensitive data protected on Amazon S3?
- Are there any rsync
  online backup options? If so, what do
  people recommend?

UPDATE: I am still unable to find any decent answers to the above questions, can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Amazon S3 is a convenient solution for the NAS backups, especially talking about a home network, and with a relatively small NAS like the DS210j.
In that aspect, in my opinion a better solution is to add some external disks for the backup (e.g. via a USB docking station, or another NAS).
There are advantages in therms of :
- costs (hard disks are relatively cheap nowadays)
- data security (sensitive data doesn't leave home)
- backup speed (one thing is do a full backup of a giga/terabyte of data via USB/eSATA,
  a totally different one is to try to do the same via WAN link)

The only advantage of S3 would be that their backup is really offline, so in case (home) disaster strikes,
a copy of our data resides safely in the amazon cloud.